# Не идет на печать на сетевом принтере Delphi

Tags: delphi, принтер

У меня есть два принтера

1-й принтер подсоединен по сети;
2-й принтер подсоединен тоже по сети, но он сетевой, то есть имеет свой ip адрес, но он раположен в другом здании в метрах около 100 м.

Теперь следующая картина, есть программа, операторы принимают заказы, формируют заказ, для приготовления заказа, у меня отправляется перечень приготовляемых блюд, и на кухню, то есть это принтер 1-й (идет нормально), и определенные блюда идут на второй принтер...

Только вот что возникает, я не пойму почему так происходит:

На 1-й принтер все нормально идет, а на второй один раз пойдет печать и все больше не идет, ошибок программа не выдает, видимо в очередь отправляет как мне кажется, но принтер 2-й не хочет печатать.

Вот что у меня есть на данный момент,

Есть файл Word типа шаблон, в программе, я вызываю, два раза

```
W.ActiveDocument.Application.Run('PrintProgDoc', PagesStr);
```

где `PrintProgDoc` - это макрос где вызывывется `printOut` для распечатки.

Не пойму в чем проблема, почему на 1-м идет печать, а на 2-й никак не хочет идти?

Comment: а если просто из ворда отправляете то норм (макросом)? ничего там в очереди печати не остается? в делфях ли проблема то?

Comment: Попробуйте в ворде записать отправку на печать макросом и посмотреть его текст. Скорее всего проблема не в делфи.